# Installed Linux Mint18.3 using Oracle Virtual Box 5.2.6 r120293 on HP 8560W

Tags: virtual-machine, linux-mint

3D acceleration does not work in Ver 5.2.6 R12093.Remove 3D acceleration the Linux Mint works normally. How to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I installed the NEW patch VboxGuestAddition_5.2.7-120226.iso, shut down the machine , and then selected the 3D acceleration in the Settings in Oracle Box.

The system works well but there still seems to be some resolution problem , the LM (linux mint logo) does not come clearly and there seems to be some resolution problem. In full screen mode the Logo disappears, re-scale it to smaller window the logo appears but not as clear and sharp as Originally it used to come prior to installing the patch. The patch works but seems there is still some issue.

Any one has experienced the same and has a solution, please let me know.